# How do you make a shortcut to a file with no extension and not have to set the app EVERY TIME

Tags: windows-explorer

I have a ROM for an emulator but it has no exstension. instead of having to open the emulator (Xenia) everytime and open the file, i want a desktop shortcut to do it for me. any ways?

Answer (score 4):

Make the shortcut to the *program* and specify the file as a parameter, in the same "Target" field:

```
Target:   "C:\Program Files\Xenia I guess\Xenia.exe" "D:\Games\SomeROM"
```

This runs the program and asks it to open the file in the same way as file associations would.